# Frequency Table with Column of Average in R

Tags: r, frequency, frequency-distribution

Given a dataframe `df` which I generate as follows:

```
set.seed(1)
b <- runif(100)
set.seed(1)
a <- sample.int(9, 100, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

I formed a frequency table as shown below but not satisfied:

```
sortted_a <- data.frame(table(df$a))
sortted_a
#  Var1 Freq
#1    1   14
#2    2    8
#3    3   10
#4    4    9
#5    5   11
#6    6   11
#7    7    5
$8    8   14
#9    9   18
```

I rather want a table that will not only show the `frequency` of `vector a` but will display `frequency of a` along with the associated `averages of vector b` as follows in `R`:

```
#  Var1 Freq   Ave_b
#1    1   14   0.6750
#2    2    8   0.0027
#3    3   10   0.8298
#4    4    9   0.1873
#5    5   11   0.3874
#6    6   11   0.7632
#7    7    5   0.5812
$8    8   14   0.5478
#9    9   18   0.4389
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with base R, you can use `tapply()` to find the average of b by a and then `cbind()` with your sorted data.frame:

```
ave_b <- tapply(df$b,df$a,mean)
new_df <- cbind(sortted_a, ave_b)
```

Answer (score 3):

In `dplyr` you can group by `a` and count the frequency and average of `b` column :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(Freq = n(), 
            b = mean(b))
```

similarly, in base R and `data.table` :

```
aggregate(b~a, df, function(x) c(Freq = length(x), b = mean(x)))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Freq = .N, b = mean(b)), a]
```